# Disnake Commands

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Is it possible to do something like this:

**/command** *option1 or option2*

**/command option1**

**/command option2** *option2a or option2b*

According to the second part of the command, there will be a third field or no field.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you have written so far.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the [`Option`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.Option) parameter for the [`SlashCommand`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#slashcommand) class? Try that and get back to us if you can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: look into autocomplete with the inter.filled_options["str"] command